# Difference in HSQL and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hsqldb, jdbctemplate

I am using MySQL as my application database, but HSQL as test in-memory database. Now the issue is I have a SQL selectQuery like below :

```
SELECT date(a.created_at) as record_date 
FROM table a
```

Now, date() is a function in MYSQL for converting DateTime to Date, but in HSQL the same function is to_date(). Now, I have a method which hits the above query to database and gets output.

```
public Response dbQueryThroughJdbcTemplate(String selectQuery){
       jdbcTemplate.query(selectQuery, RowMapper); //RowMapper maps output to Response  
    }
```

Now, I have a test method for testing this method,

```
@Test
public void testDbQueryThroughJdbcTemplate(){
       Response response = dbQueryThroughJdbcTemplate(selectQuery);
       TestCase.assertEquals(expected, response); // avoided the code for making expected object
}
```

Now, as the test environment is using HSQL db, the test throws an error that date method is not available.

How to come out of this issue, or any better way to achieve this?

Comment: A test on what? HSQL works, you don't need to test that. Test you get the right results which is independent of the query mechanism used. If the problem is that you need to completely change the query: you shouldn't be doing that. Either use MySQL, or mock the database calls.

Comment: @Gimby, updated the question to make it more clear

Comment: As I said, you're testing the wrong things. MySQL's date function and HSQL's date functions work, you don't need to test that. What you should be testing is how your application responds to the outcome of a query, and that allows you to take the database out of the test by mocking it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try an alternative that is supported by both HSQLDB and MySQL

```
SELECT CAST(a.created_at AS DATE) as record_date FROM table a
```